# Appending a new field with unique id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have code which takes a name and a number. I want to have a button that, when you click it, adds another field for another name and number, but it should have a different id because I need to use it for later.

So far, I have the code below but it doesn't work.

```js
function addField() {
  var id = 2
  var name = 'Name of Owner # ' + id
  var phonenum = 'Phone number'

  $('.form-group').append('<br><label for="' + id + '">' + name + ':</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="NewPnOwner" id="NewPnOwner' + id + '" />')

  $('.form-group').append('<br><label for="' + id + '">' + phonenum + ':</label><input type="number" class="form-control" name="NewPnNumber" id="NewPnNumber' + id + '"/>')

  id++;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-sm-4">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>
      <code>New Phone Number</code>
    </legend>

    <label for="NewPnOwner">Name of Owner #1:&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="NewPnOwner" id="NewPnOwner" />
    <br />
    <label for="Phonenumber">Phone number: &nbsp;&nbsp; </label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="NewPnNumber" id="NewPnNumber" />
    <br />    
    <input type="button" id="button" value="Add New Field" onclick="addField()" />
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: You should declare `id` outside the function.

Comment: You're redeclaring `id` with a value of `2` each time that function runs. So, yeah, move `var id = 2` outside the function. However `id`s with consecutive numbers are bad practice and not needed, ever.

Comment: Don't use incremental id attributes as it's an anti pattern. Use common classes and DOM traversal instead.

Comment: Here's one way to do this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/3hrg6ase/

Comment: @ChrisG thank you, your code is a lot less complicated than mine. for the id i did it to increment because i need to call on each specific one later on and that was the solution i came up with to do so

Comment: You can use something like `$('#phoneNumbers fieldset').eq(2)` to grab the 3rd `<fieldset>` though. It depends on what exactly you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Just define `id` outside the function like this, otherwise it will initialize with value `2` on every call of `addField()`.

```js
var id = 2
function addField() {
  var name = 'Name of Owner # ' + id
  var phonenum = 'Phone number'

  $('.form-group').append('<br><label for="' + id + '">' + name + ':</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="NewPnOwner" id="NewPnOwner' + id + '" />')

  $('.form-group').append('<br><label for="' + id + '">' + phonenum + ':</label><input type="number" class="form-control" name="NewPnNumber" id="NewPnNumber' + id + '"/>')

  id++;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-sm-4">
  <fieldset>
    <legend><code>New Phone Number</code></legend>

    <label for="NewPnOwner">Name of Owner #1:&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="NewPnOwner" id="NewPnOwner">
    <br>
    <label for="Phonenumber">Phone number: &nbsp;&nbsp; </label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="NewPnNumber" id="NewPnNumber" />
<br>    
<input type="button" id="button" value="Add New Field" onclick="addField()" />
  </fieldset>

</div>
```

### But

even though that this is the correct solution to your problem, I would not recommend you to give them ids like that. I can't think of any valid reason to solve any problem like so. There are probably better solutions for your real problem.

Comment: thank you for the help, i really struggled with the dynamic id and that was the solution i came up with

Comment: No problem but as said, its probably better to do it another way. random ids are never good, @gravestones